# Error al ejecutar yarn create react-app

Tags: reactjs

Hola estoy intentando crear mi primer proyecto con react.
Primeramente ejecute npm i -g yarn
Después ejecute el comando "yarn create react-app miprimerapp" me arroja el siguiente error, Alguien sabe como puedo solucionarlo de antemano gracias.
Mi version de node es 12.18.1 y de npm 6.14.5
En mis variables de entorno si esta npm
equipo: windows10

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este error es común cuando tu usuario tiene espacios, existen varias soluciones, pero yo te recomendaria usar npx para crear tu app con `npx create-react-app miprimerapp --use-npm

Comment: Gracias Jonathan confirmo que si el usuario provocaba el error, Ya lo arreglé muchas gracias por tu ayuda